# how match mixed type of scala higher-kinder types feature with java generic type?

Tags: java, scala, generics, types, scala-java-interop

my project is mixed java and scala language, but some type mismatch error occur and I think it's a common problem in term of java and scala communicate.
I organized the stage with simple classes. Environment is java 1.8 and scala 2.11.7

```
class Item[+T](name: String)

//ready use Item as MM type
class Packet[+MM[_]]

object GenS extends App {
  //use Item class
  def doWithPacket(packet: Packet[Item]) = {}

  //type error occur on packetFormJava variable form java
  val packetFormJava = GetGenJ.newPacketInJava
  doWithPacket(packetFormJava)

  //run well
  val packetFromScala = new Packet[Item]
  doWithPacket(packetFromScala)
}
```

and the java class simple as this:

```
public class GetGenJ {
    public static Packet<Item> newPacketInJava() {
        return new Packet<Item>();
    }
}
```

The compile error encounter:

```
Error:(16, 16) type mismatch;  
 found   : Packet[Item[_]]  
 required: Packet[Item]  
  doWithPacket(packetFormJava)  
                  ^
```

any help or advice thanks.

Comment: In other word, how does the java represent scala's Packet[Item[_]] type?

Comment: Is adding a utility method in Scala an option? That might be the easiest solution. I'm not sure you can represent higher kinded types in Java at all.

Comment: hi @0__ ,Item[ _ ] should be represent a higher kind type in Java. It seem I might avoid Java code return a higher kind type.thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other word, how does the java represent scala's Packet[Item[_]] type?

It doesn't. Java simply doesn't have higher-kinded types. The information that `MM` is higher-kinded is hidden inside `@ScalaSignature`.

When you write `Packet<Item>`, you are using a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/9204) (which, in turn, can't be represented in Scala); you couldn't use `Item<Something>` inside `newPacketInJava`.

Comment: thanks, I will avoid do the high kinder types in java.The discuss about raw type seems it was a legacy problem.happy new year~