# How to export Scala Transformation to Java

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I'm trying to implement a Scala trait by Java, the trait has a generic container type within another container, which couldn't be solved automatically by java import, the Scala code is below:

```
import cats.data.{EitherNel, Kleisli, NonEmptyList}
import cats.implicits._

package Export_To_Java {
    package object types {
        type Valid[A] = EitherNel[String, A]
        type ValidOperation[A, B] = Kleisli[Valid, A, B]
        type Amount = BigDecimal
    }

    trait InterestService[Account] {
        import types._

        type InterestOperation = ValidOperation[Account, Option[Amount]]
        type TaxOperation = ValidOperation[Option[Amount], Amount]

        def computeInterest: InterestOperation
        def computeTax: TaxOperation
    }
}
```

Once it has been implemented by Java, Intellij automatically generates methods:

```
import cats.data.Kleisli;
import cats.data.NonEmptyList;
import Export_To_Java.InterestService;
import scala.math.BigDecimal;
import scala.util.Either;


public class JavaInterestService<Account> implements InterestService<Account> {
    @Override
    public Kleisli<Either<NonEmptyList<String>, A>, Account, Option<BigDecimal>> computeInterest() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public Kleisli<Either<NonEmptyList<String>, A>, Option<BigDecimal>, BigDecimal> computeTax() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now You will see the java method return type has been extended to `Either<NonEmptyList<String>, A>` which still has an generic parameter `A` inside, which is carried form Scala type `Valid[A]`. Error message is:

```
Error:(13, 82) java: computeInterest() in JavaInterestService cannot implement computeInterest() in Export_To_Java.InterestService
  return type cats.data.Kleisli<scala.util.Either<cats.data.NonEmptyList<java.lang.String>,A>,Account,scala.Option<scala.math.BigDecimal>> is not compatible with cats.data.Kleisli<scala.util.Either,Account,scala.Option<scala.math.BigDecimal>>
```

Remove type from Either will get error:

```
[error] JavaInterestService.java:13:82: scala.util.Either takes two type parameters, expected: one
[error]     public Kleisli<Either, Option<BigDecimal>, BigDecimal> computeInterest() {
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

sbt configuration:

```
val scalaTestVersion = "3.0.5"
val catsVersion = "1.6.0"

lazy val ShapelessGuide = (project in file(".")).
        settings(
            name := "test",
            version := "0.1",
            scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
            libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestVersion % Test,
                "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % catsVersion
            ),
            scalacOptions ++= Seq(
                "-language:higherKinds",
                "-deprecation",
                "-encoding", "UTF-8",
                "-Ypartial-unification",
                "-feature",
                "-language:_"
            )
        )
```

I'm wondering is it possible to implement a Scala trait in Java? or what's the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public class JavaInterestService<Account> implements InterestService<Account> {
    @Override
    public Kleisli<Either, Account, Option<BigDecimal>> computeInterest() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public Kleisli<Either, Option<BigDecimal>, BigDecimal> computeTax() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Java compiler can see higher-kinded Scala types as raw types
[how match mixed type of scala higher-kinder types feature with java generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542191/how-match-mixed-type-of-scala-higher-kinder-types-feature-with-java-generic-type)

Comment: Yes, actually I had tried to remove the type parameters from Either, but compiler reported another error: `scala.util.Either takes two type parameters, expected: one`.

Comment: And Intellij was also warning the method was `attempting to use incompatible return type`.

Comment: @user3593261 The code compiles without errors https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/3dab1f318757e1b30d3bf8b3de097ee3 IntelliJ warnings are irrelevant.

Comment: That's weird, it can't pass my compiler, my java version is `1.8.0_152`, what's yours?

Comment: 1.8.0_162. Do `sbt compile`. What is the result?

Comment: Yes, It is `sbt compile`. I updated the post by adding the error.

Comment: What is your `build.sbt`?

Comment: Try to do `sbt clean compile`. Try to import my project https://github.com/DmytroMitin/test and run `sbt compile`.

Comment: Great!, it passed with `clean`! Thanks! you safe my day!!